# How to "mount" an Angular 2 module's routes at a certain point in the routing hierarchy

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Say I have main routing module defined like this:

```
// app-routing.module.ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'auth',
        component: MasterPageComponent,
        canActivate: CanActivateGuard
    }
];
```

And then in another file a `feature` routing module:

```
// feature-routing.module.ts
const featureRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '/feature',
        component: FeatureComponent
    }
];
```

How can I "mount" the routes from my feature module under my main module, so I access it like this:

```
/auth/feature
```

Conceptually I'm looking for something like:

```
RouterModule.forChildAtMountPoint(featureRoutes, '/auth');
```

I know this is possible with lazy loading, but I want this module to be loaded eagerly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very straightforward, though as far as I can see *still* not yet [documented](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes).

Although a route definition's `loadChildren` property is typically associated with [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#lazy-loading-modules-with-the-router), it can also be assigned a function that returns an eagerly loaded module:

```
// app-routing.module.ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'auth',
        component: MasterPageComponent,
        canActivate: [CanActivateGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'feature',
                loadChildren: () => FeatureModule
            }
        ]
    }
];

// feature-routing.module.ts
const featureRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ''
        component: FeatureComponent
    }
];
```